# How to append to existing config file using ConfigObj?

Tags: python, python-3.x, configobj

I am attempting to use `ConfigObj` to write to a config file with a function.

```
#!/usr/bin/evn python3.5

import configobj

def createConfig(path):
    config = configobj.ConfigObj()
    config.filename = path
    config[REFNAME] = {}
    config[REFNAME]['URL'] = URL
    config.write()

REFNAME = input("Enter a reference name :")
URL= input("Enter a URL :")

createConfig('server.ini')
```

When the function `createConfig()` is called the config file is written, however, if the script runs again it overwrites the config file created previously. I want to preserve the previous entires and only add to the file, or overwrite if the same `REFNAME` is provided.

I'm having trouble understanding how to do this from the docs:

https://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configobj.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] that can be run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the  link, I reworked my question and provided a better example which you can use to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the path to the settings file to the `ConfigObj()` initializer along with a `create_empty=True` argument, it will create an empty file only when the file doesn't already exist—thereby allowing the any existing file to be updated.

This is explained in the [ConfigObj specifications](https://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configobj.html#configobj-specifications) section of the documentation where it describes what keyword arguments the method accepts.

```
import configobj

def createConfig(path):
    config = configobj.ConfigObj(path, create_empty=True)
    config[REFNAME] = {}
    config[REFNAME]['URL'] = URL
    config.write()

REFNAME = input("Enter a reference name: ")
URL= input("Enter a URL: ")

createConfig('server.ini')
```

Note you might want to change the name of the function to `openConfig()` since that is what it now does.